# General function for executing time measurement

Tags: c, function, pointers, reference

I'm currently trying to write a general function to measure the time another function `func` needs for execution. I'm able to calculate the time with `<time.h>` and so on.

My approach looks something like this:

```
 void measure_time(void *(func)(), unsigned loops);
```

For now it is enough if the result is just printed within `measure_time` (later I could let `measure_time` return some information).

I'm able to calculate the execution time and so on (with `<time.h>`) but at the moment my problem is that I want this to be a *general* function and it should be able to take all sort of functions 'func' with different return types and different argument sizes/types.

Currently I have no clue how I could manage to give `measure_time` the function 'func' and let it execute it with arguments I am able to specify.

For example:

```
int a[1000] = {15, 53, ..., 42};
void sort_something(int *a, int n_elements) { ... };
void measure_time(sort_somthing(a, 1000), 100);
```

This should call `sort_something` 100 times with the arguments "a and 1000" and measure the time needed for the execution.

I'm more than happy to give some more information if you need them.

Cheers!

LastSeconds

Comment: because of the inequality of function pointers with different type+number of arguments, this may not be possible. however you can easily wrap this up in a macro ( part of the macro containing the call to the function as specified by user )

Comment: Could you give with me a rough idea for the macro please?

Comment: You could explore passing a function to a function by looking at how `qsort` takes it. And you could explore variable other arguments by looking up `va_start` and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general scheme should be:

```
void general_timer(void (*function)(void *context), void *context, int loops);
```

This takes a function that returns no value and takes a single `void *` argument for context, and passes the context.  Depending on what you need to pass as context, that might be the address of a structure, or something as simple as a `FILE *`.

Inside the implementation:

```
void general_timer(void (*function)(void *context), void *context, int loops)
{
    Clock clk;
    clk_init(&clk);
    clk_start(&clk);
    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++
        (*function)(context);
    clk_stop(&clk);
    char buffer[32];
    printf("%s seconds for %d iterations\n",
           clk_elapsed_microsecs(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)), loops);
}
```

Where the type `Clock` and the functions starting `clk_` are parts of a high-resolution timing package, using whatever is convenient.

You could write the function call as:

```
function(context);
```

It would work exactly the same.  This is the more modern style; I prefer the old-fashioned `(*function)(context)` call as it makes it clear that `function` is a function pointer, not the name of a function.  YMMV.

Yes, I do have a specific implementation of such a package.  However, the concept applies readily regardless of how you implement it.

You might have a function to be timed.  It might use the structure:

```
struct TwoFiles
{
    FILE *f_in;
    FILE *f_out;
};
```

and the function might be:

```
void file_copier(void *ctxt)
{
    struct TwoFiles *info = ctxt;
    char buffer[4096];
    size_t bytes;
    rewind(info->f_in);
    rewind(info->f_out);
    while ((bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), sizeof(char), info->f_in)) > 0)
    {
        if (frwite(buffer, bytes, sizeof(char), info->f_out) != bytes)
        {
            …report error…abandon loop…
        }
    }
}
```

and the call might be:

```
struct TwoFiles ctxt;
ctxt.f_in = fopen(some_file_name, "r");
ctxt.f_out = fopen(another_name, "w");

general_timer(file_copier, &ctxt, 100);
```

Note that to be useful, the file copier function needed to rewind the input and output file streams so that it would do work each time the general timer function calls it.  That is, however, a detail for the specific task on hand.

Comment: This is great and probably what I'll use. Thank you really much!

Comment: The only thing that bothers me a little is that I have to rewrite a lot of functions which I want to test to only take one argument. That is correct, isn't it? It's still something I'll probably go with!

Comment: More likely, you'd write wrappers: `void real_file_copier(FILE *fin, FILE *fout){ …original code… }` and then `void timed_file_copier(void *context) { struct TwoFiles *f2 = context; real_file_copier(f2->f_in,f2->f_out); }`.  So, yes, you get to write a number of functions; but they're individually tiny and simply wrap the code you really want to time.